# Best way to run a series of short animations?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I basically have a song that a cartoon needs to dance to.

Is it better to have :

Version A: one full song and dispatch a bunch of queues:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
        //Have the figure dance move 1
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
        //Have the figure dance move 2
     }
```

Or segment the song and actions:

```
   func dancing(){
     timeElapsed += 1
     if timeElapsed == 1 {
        \\figure does move 1
        self.playSound()
     } else if timeElapsed == 2 {
        \\figure does move 2
        self.playSound2()
     }
```

As a summary:

Version a: Dispatch multiple queues at the same time

Version b: Segment the queues, but that would mean my project would have 10+ media files

Is there anyway to test this? Or any alternative methods? I've poked around and seen things like concurrent/sync queues, but don't know much on how to use them in practice.

Comment: please checkout my answer .. it may help you

Comment: Hard to tell since we don't know what kind of animations you'll be performing but I would use SpriteKit or at least a CADisplayLink. Every frame I would check the current time of the audio player and update the content accordingly. If you use UIView.animate or dispatch queues you might find your animation getting out of sync, specially if the app is suspended.

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t want too much nesting, you can use `UIViewPropertyAnimator`. For Example:

```
let animation1 = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, curve: .linear) {
    // animation code
}

let animation2 = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .linear) {
    // animation code
}

animation1.addCompletion { _ in
    animation2.startAnimation()
}

animation1.startAnimation()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option you might want to look at is UIView key frame animations.
You need to figure out your relative start times and durations, but it's a bit nicer than using dispatch queues.

More info: [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622552-animatekeyframes)

A simple demonstration:

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 4.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
    // Animation 1 that starts immediately and runs for 2 seconds
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
        // Perform animation
    }

    // Animation 2 that starts after 2 seconds and runs for 2 seconds
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
        // Perform animation
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I will go with Version A: one full song and Set the Animation Hierarchy

Better to use UIView Animation with completion block

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        //animation 1
    }, completion: { (value: Bool) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            //animation 2
        })
    })
```